# standard error of conditional survival probability

Tags: survival, conditional-probability, standard-error

Let $$S(t|t-1) := \frac{P(T>t)}{P(T> t-1)} = \frac{S(t)}{S(t-1)}$$ be the conditional survival probability. I have two questions.

1. Assuming $\text{SE}(S(t))$ and $\text{SE}(S(t-1))$ (as well as $S(t)$ and $S(t-1)$) are provided in the data, what would be $\text{SE}(S(t|t-1))$?
2. How should we define $S(t|t-1)$ when $S(t-1) = 0$, how about $\text{SE}(S(t|t-1))$ in this corner case?

Comment: Because $S$ is a *function,* not a random variable, please explain what a standard error for it would be and how one can "provide" such a function in the data.  If you are trying to ask about *estimating* $S$ from data, please describe the data, your assumptions about the data generation process, and tell us what procedure you are using to estimate it, because the answer depends on all that.

Comment: @whuber The data is Kaplan Meier survival probability estimate for a specific cancer for each stratum (year of diagnosis, age, gender, etc) provided by SEER software. For each stratum, the survival probability and standard error is provided. I am trying to calculate the the  survival probability of first year post diagnosis, second year post diagnosis conditional on first year, 3rd year conditional on second year and so on and  their corresponding standard errors.